# python annotate count with filter datetime

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have model Token:

```
class Token(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  ...
```

I have model Phrase which has a fk to token

```
class Phrase(models.Model):
  token = models.ForeignKey(Token, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
    related_name = "phrases")
  frequency = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to perform a complex query
As result I want to have list of objects with token names and phrases filtered by some param count, like this:

```
[{'name':'token1', 'phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100': 50},{'name':'token2', 'phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100': 250}]
```

How do I do this?
I know I can do this using annotate function, but not sure how.
So far I am doing it by simply iterating through token objects but this is not effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
tokens.annotate(phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100=Count(Q(phrases__freq__gte=100))).values('name','phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100')
```

Comment: Some explanation to go along with the answer would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can query on your Token model using annotate function so you can produce column required 'phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100'. Following query will return you the query object with above column (variable):

```
tokens = tokens.annotate(phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100=Count(phrases__frequency__gt=100))
```

Now, either you can iterate 'tokens' query object or to get direct list of dictionaries use values function in above query like:

```
tokens.annotate(phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100=Count(phrases__frequency__gt=100)).values('name','phrases_with_freq_greater_than_100')
```